# Are Federal "rank-up" missions always combat based?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I'm interested in the Federal ships, and I need to up my rank with the Feds to get one. I did some Fed missions and traded a lot, now I have this Federal Naval mission that says my actions have been noticed, and if I go kill a spy somewhere, I'll be upgraded to Ensign.

**I'm a miner in a Type-7. I have no shields, and 4 mining lasers.** I have a buddy who plays as my bodyguard, but he isn't always around, and obviously can't complete missions for me, so I'm going to have a tough time with this first-tier naval mission, and I expect to fail the later ones without a complete change up in my ship and play style.

**Are rank-up missions always combat based, or can they be mining / trading missions too?** I like to live dangerously as much as the next guy (again, no shields), but if every rank-up for Feds is achieved via a combat mission,  I'll forget about the Fed ships for now and focus on a Type-9 or an Orca instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**. Some rank up missions are based around delivering commodities, though in many cases, they want weapons, which are illegal in many federal jurisdictions.

That said, many rank up missions are combat based, so it may be worth investing in a rudimentary combat vessel as a second ship if you're looking to ride in a ship that requires federation rank.

Comment: Also, I know for sure at lower ranks, trade missions do happen, but it might be the case that there are more combat ones as you rank up. Not sure